# Analytic function with zero-derivatives

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, analytic-functions

Suppose $f$ is analytic at $z=0$, and $f(0)=f'(0)=f''(0)=0$. I am to show that there is a function $g$ analytic at $0$ such that $f(z)= z^3g(x)$ in a neighborhood of $0$.
I really do not know how to approach this question, hence I seek guidance.

Comment: What have you tried?  What are you thoughts?  If you don't know how to approach this question, you should review your notes.

Comment: i have tried equating g(x) with the derivative of f(x) but really do not know where to plug in the Z^3.

Comment: I have edited your question. You can click the "Edit" button to see how I wrote in math mode. You should check the guide on how to use MathJax to typeset equations.

Comment: in addition, it is a personal study born out of inquisitiveness in a bid to improve my math skills

Comment: If $f$ is analytic at $0$, then you can represent it as a power series centred at $0$ in some disk. Conversely, if you can represent a function as a power series on a disk, it must be analytic. Try representing $f$ as a power series, and seeing what $g$ must be.

Comment: Yes, as @TheoBendit notes, you need to use the definition of an analytic function.

Comment: Do it one step at a time. Suppose $f(z) = 0$ then show that there is some analytic $h$ such that $f(z) = z h(z)$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: if $f$ is analytic at $z=0$ and $$f(0)=f''(0)=f''(0)=0,$$
then
$$
\begin{align}
f(z)=&
f(0)+f'(0)z+\frac 12 f''(0)z^2+\frac 16 f'''(0)z^3+\ldots
\\
=&\frac 16 f'''(0)z^3+\frac{1}{24}f^{(4)}(0)z^4+\frac{1}{120}f^{(5)}(0)z^5+\ldots
\\
=&z^3\times\ldots
\end{align}
$$